# angularJS + socket.io: Only working one way

Tags: javascript, node.js, angularjs, socket.io

I have a problem with angularJS + node + socketio. In my application its possible to send data from client to server via socket.emit('enteredUsername', 'Guest'); like in controlls.js. But it doesnt work from server to client. After the server receives 'enteredUsername' he should emit 'UsernameOk' back. But he doesnt... Or he sends it, but the controller doesn't receives it. Is there something wrong, because I have more than one controller?

Anyone has an idea?

**Edit1:**

Okay, fixed it, by using `io.sockets.emit('enteredUsername', username)` instead of `socket.emit('enteredUsername', username)` on the server side.

server.js

```
var express = require('express'),
    app = express(),
    server = require('http').createServer(app),
    io = require('socket.io').listen(server);

app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));

io.sockets.on('connection', function(socket) {
     console.log('client connected!');

    socket.on('enteredUsername', function(data) {
        console.log('Username: ' + data);
        socket.broadcast.emit('UsernameOk', data);
        socket.emit('UsernameOk', data);
    });


});

server.listen(1337);
```

services.js

```
angular.module('myApp.services', [])
    .factory('socket', function($rootScope) {
        var socket = io.connect();
        return {
            on: function(eventName, callback) {
                socket.on(eventName, function() {
                    var args = arguments;
                    $rootScope.$apply(function() {
                        callback.apply(socket, args);
                    });
                });
            },
            emit: function(eventName, data, callback) {
                socket.emit(eventName, data, function() {
                    var args = arguments;
                    $rootScope.$apply(function() {
                        if(callback) {
                            callback.apply(socket, args);
                        }
                    });
                });
            }
        };
    });
```

controllers.js

```
angular.module('myApp.controllers', [])
    .controller('usernameCtrl', ['$scope', 'socket', function($scope, socket) {
        $scope.username = 'guest';

        $scope.EnteredUsername = function() {
            var username = $scope.username;
            socket.emit('enteredUsername', username);
        }

        socket.on('UsernameOk', function(data) {
            console.log('Client-Get: UsernameOk -> ' + data);
        });
    }]);
```

Comment: Haha!, I was learning it. I understood angularJS + socket.io just by your query.  Thanks for your  query ;)

Comment: I've been having a problem that on the client the socket.emit does not work inside a scope method, but it works outside the method, any hints?